# Resizing images - Browser vs Photoshop

Tags: image, browser, web, photoshop, resize

I have a client who insists on "crisp" images on his Web pages. One image he gave me was 2592 pixels wide, but the page is only 940 pixels wide. No problem, I just resize the images using Photoshop but there is a noticeable drop in quality, lots of jagged edges. I expect a loss of quality when resizing to one-third the size, but I thought I could do better. So what I did is take the original image and have the browser (Chrome) resize it to 940 pixels wide. Yes, I understand this is the absolute worst thing to do but I was just experimenting. It turns out the browser does a much better job of resizing than Photoshop -- I don't get the jagged edges and the picture looks fairly close to the original in quality.

So what's the deal here? Why is Photoshop not as good as resizing as Chrome (IE8 and Firefox do just as good a job too)? I've tried tweaking Photoshop's resampling options but have seen no real difference.

Comment: In the Image Size popup in photoshop, there's a dropdown at the bottom with option (Nearest neighbour, bicubic etc).. have you tried the different options there ?

Comment: You shouldn't have a loss of quality when shrinking a picture in Photoshop ( if you're doing it correctly ofcourse ). You're probably losing quality at save.
When saving a picture Photoshop gives you options at what quality do you want to save the picture. Make sure you're selecting the highest one

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different things to take into account when scaling images in photoshop:

---

**1.) File type+compression**

You're going to want to make sure that if you use a filetype with lossy compression (i.e. JPEG) that you set the quality >8, or you will see a noticeable drop on quality.

**2.) Resample method**

Photoshop provides a few different resampling methods which effect how pixels are combined when scaling down. Below are links to some images that illustrate where you can modify this when scaling.

Image->Image Size...

http://cl.ly/3W3M0b3W3H0G1Y452L15

There is a drop-down on the bottom of this window:

http://cl.ly/0o463J2J0e2L1u0C1U26

Likely what you're experiencing is that your image is resampling using "Nearest Neighbor" or Bilinear".

---

Give it a go.

Comment: I've tried every resampling option PS offers. Even within Photoshop, the results look jagged. This is prior to being saved as JPG/GIF/PNG.

Comment: Could you please post a link to the image? And the one that you resized using PS. I will give it a go and comment with my results.

Comment: Sure, check it out here:
http://www.360degreedigital.com/test/index.php

The first image is full size, 2592 x 414.
The second image is browser-resized to 940 x 150.
The third image is Photoshop-resized to 940 x 150, saved as a PNG-24 non-interlaced image.

Zoom in and pay attention to the line at the top of the building's peak... that's where I can easily see the difference. Frankly, I can't tell much difference at 100% zoom, but the client says he can... he must have a really nice monitor.

Comment: Fourth image on that page is the same PS-reduced image saved as PNG-8.

Comment: By the way, I know that the browser has an advantage when zooming in because it has the original image it can resize whereas the PS image is static and becomes lossy as you zoom.

Comment: So, is the client on the new Retina display Macbook Pro? Because there REALLY isn't much ANY difference. If the client is nitpicking on this image that is nigh perfect and much better than 99% of the images you find on the internet, then something else is the matter. Or he/she is just trolling. Just saying. You aren't doing anything wrong and it looks A-OK on my Apple Cinema Display

Comment: On the other hand, your client's browser zoom level may be wrong. Ask him or her to press Command-0 (Control-0 on windows) to make sure that the page is the correct size.

Comment: When I redid in PS to post the example, for whatever reason it seems to have come out a bit better. Before I could see a difference, now not so much... or maybe my eyes are tired. I bet you're right about the browser zoom level, though. That may be why it looks sharper with the full-res version than the resized one, because the browser can resample to fit the zoom level and not lose quality.

Comment: Here's the happy medium: http://www.360degreedigital.com/test/test.htm. First image is the original, full size. Second image is a full-size image saved as 50% JPG (55k), but browser-resized. Zoom in and the second image retains its quality, but is still a manageable size (it's the only image on the page).

Comment: Indeed, very nice. Though I still think you should educate your client on browser scale, as so many people are not!

Comment: I also have about the same problem. Whenever I use an editor (Adobe Lightroom or anything else) to resize the image it looks less sharp than if I just zoom out the bigger original image in the viewer to have the same size on the screen as the editor resized image. And it doesn't matter what viewer or image editor I use - zoomed out original image always looks sharper than the resized image. Setting the jpg quality to 100% while resizing in the editor doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a browser-based script such as TimThumb: http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/

You really do need to resize the image instead of shrinking a huge image just to display. This script will create copies of your image in different sizes and if I remember correctly, it even supports some sort of caching.

Ive had it resize pretty large images for me to very small thumbnails and it always looked sharp.

Comment: Not a bad solution, but results for me were comparable to Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop and web browsers handle resizing differently. I don't use Photoshop, so I can't help you with that..

However, if you want that the picture looks like resized by a web browser, then resize it with a web browser! Take a screenshot and cut the resized picture, creating another one which you can really use on the site.

Comment: I've actually tried this method. It works pretty well, but I was hoping there was an easier way in Photoshop.